# JSTL.JAR can not be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am getting the following error while using the `jstl` in my spring mvc app.

```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri:
> http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml
> or the jar files deployed
```

I have downloaded and copied the `jstl-api-1.2.jar` in my `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/` directory same location as other libraries.

my `web.xml` file looks like below.

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
            <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
            <welcome-file-list>
                    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            </welcome-file-list>


            <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>
                            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                    </servlet-class>
                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

and my `spring-servlet.xml` file looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


        <context:component-scan
                base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

        <bean id="viewResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass"
                        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
</beans>
```

and the header of JSP file where I am using the tag is set like below.

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

I can confirm I have placed the `jstl-api-1.2.jar` correctly under the lib directory. Please help me sort out the issue.

**EDIT**

My LIB path

```
[muneer@maxhost Spring3MVC]$ ls WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/
commons-logging.jar                              org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
jstl-api-1.2.jar                                 org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar      org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar    org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
```

the below but was removed which I had previously included in my web.xml by mistakenly.

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Maven in your project?

Small Observation ,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

Should not be in web.xml  , It is maven POM's Dependency Management Structure [ DTD Definition ]

Comment: I am not using maven. I just copied these part from one site when searching for solution for the above issue. I have to remove it any way.

Comment: @BlueBird using maven or not, seems that you're lacking the JSTL libraries in your WEB-INF/lib path. Just put them there and you should be set.

Comment: really that file in in my lib path same as all other jar. check my directory structure in edit please

Comment: @BlueBird if that's right, then clean your application server, rebuild your web application and redeploy it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, did several times. but same result. i am confused.

Comment: @BlueBird looks like you have something very specific to your environment that isn't posted in your question, and sadly we don't have a crystal ball to see what may happen in your environment.

Comment: if i removed the tag part from jsp, everything works. and is this the file `jstl-api-1.2.jar` correct one? I downloaded several `jstl` and tried. same issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51152/discussion-between-bluebird-and-luiggi-mendoza)

Answer (score 0):

you cant write dependency tag in web.xml its part of pom.xml. if you are not using maven then make sure you have added that jar in **java build path** and **lib** folder.